# Android Facebook login release key

Tags: android

In debug mode I used a relative code snippet to get the keyhash and it worked. Now in release mode, I downloaded openssl and opened a terminal in Android Studio. I entered this line :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

But it gives this error :

```
 | was unexpected at this time.
```

What does it mean? How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape it: `%|` . if some characters cause errors on terminal, you can put `%` character before it.